# Is it correct to call the modifier's value modifiee?

Tags: suffixes

The reason for my question was part of doing documentation for my program. I commented on my For statement since it is an array that has two associated elements. Thus, the comment went on as follows:

```
//   For each given status and the desired modifiee
```

It got me curious to know if the suffix was applied in any other media. Turns out, a quick web search shows no mentions of it. The logic of my applied suffix took inspiration from the words Employer and Employee.

Thus, my question is simple: Would it be technically correct to call the modifier's value modifiee, or is the English language really that weird?

Comment: Up to now, there is no word "modifiee".  You can invent the word simply by starting to use it, if you wish.

Comment: It's probably fine in software documentation where it's more important to be clear than to write fine prose: as you say, the meaning is obvious. (Although some software style guides may disagree and require words that pass some spell-check.) I'd be more wary of using it in formal writing.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a summary of the entry for the suffix "-ee" in the OED:

The -ee suffix has two functions and origins. The first originates in Norman French legal terms. The words appear in  pairs: verb**or** -> verb**ee**. (to mortgage -> mortgagor - mortgagee / To appeal -> appellor -> appellee, etc.) However, these are only applicable to persons.

Even nonce words sender - sendee, educator - educatee, relate to persons.

(There are a few words that have caught on that have either their root in a noun (bargee) or no agent noun (devotee.))

The second is used as a diminutive - its origin is "obscure" (I suspect "baby-language"), "bootee", "setee", "goatee", etc., and does not fit your context.

In short - modifyee does not work.

Comment: Operators operate on their operands, multipliers multiply their multiplicands, and modifiers modify their modificands. Subtrahends I'll leave to your imagination.